# Bootstrap datepicker disabling past dates without current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I wanted to disable all past date before current date, not with current date. I am trying by bootstrap datepicker library "[bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker)" and using following code:

```
$('#date').datepicker({ 
    startDate: new Date() 
});
```

It works fine. But it is disabling date till today.

As example if today is 04-20-2013 and i disable past dates by setting startDate: new Date(). but I am able to select date from 04-21-2013.

UPDATED: i can solve it as following for UTC zone:

```
var d = new Date();
options["startDate"] = new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1));
```

or `startDate: "+0d"`

But these methods don't work when UTC is a day ahead. For my client in California that means at 5:00 pm my client can no longer select his local current date as a valid date. In order to fix this I am temporarily using `startDate: "-1d"`, but of course before 5 that means yesterday is visible.

Has anyone come up with a better method for now as I do not want to tell users to put in a UTC date?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 2.0.4+
jQuery 1.7.1+?

Comment: I am using Bootstrap v2.2.1 and jQuery 1.8.1

Answer (score 62):

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);

$('#date').datepicker({ 
    startDate: date
});
```

Comment: if the timezone will changed in future, what will happen?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. You might want to take a look at this thread: [Need to display local times over DST transitions using Javascript Date Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310560/need-to-display-local-times-over-dst-transitions-using-javascript-date-object)

Comment: i got TypeError: option startDate is not recognized! do you know the problem

Comment: Your Script was short to use, but it allows user to select yesterday's date. but [this](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/438) **solution works**. Hope helps.

Comment: is there anyway that this can be done dynamically and not set in the options?

Answer (score 25):

Use [minDate](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#minmaxdate)

```
var date = new Date();
var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());

$('#date').datepicker({ 
    minDate: today
});
```

Comment: for simplicity use `moment.js` like `minDate: moment()`

Comment: Just so future users are aware, this solution is for a different plugin ('bootstrap-datetimepicker').

Answer (score 24):

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="my_date" value="4/26/2015" class="datepicker">
```

JS

```
jQuery(function() {
  var datepicker = $('input.datepicker');

  if (datepicker.length > 0) {
    datepicker.datepicker({
      format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
      startDate: new Date()
    });
  }
});
```

That will highlight the default date as 4/26/2015 (Apr 26, 2015) in the calendar when opened and
disable all the dates before current date.

Answer (score 19):

use

```
startDate: '-0d'
```

Like

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    startDate: '-0d',
    changeMonth: true
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the data attribute:

```
<div class="datepicker" data-date-start-date="+1d"></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

```js
var nowDate = new Date();
var today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
 $('#date').datetimepicker({
  startDate: today
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

The solution is much simpler:

```
$('#date').datepicker({ 
    startDate: "now()" 
});
```

Try [Online Demo](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=embedded&format=&weekStart=&startDate=now()&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) and fill input Start date: **now()**

Comment: Just for info, ```startDate: "tomorrow" ``` or ```startDate: "yesterday" ``` also work if needed.

Answer (score 5):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    todayHighlight:'TRUE',
    startDate: '-0d',
    autoclose: true,
})
```

Comment: Could you explain why this should work and why it's a better solution than the accepted answer from 2 years ago?

Answer (score 4):

Here it is

```
 <script>
          $(function () {
              var date = new Date();
              date.setDate(date.getDate() - 7);

            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                maxDate: 'now',
                showTodayButton: true,
                showClear: true,
                minDate: date
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try it :

```
$(function () {
     $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({  minDate:new Date()});
});
```

Answer (score 4):

To disable past dates & highlight today's date:

```
$(function () {
    $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
        startDate : new Date(),
        todayHighlight : true
    });
});
```

To disable future dates & highlight today's date:

```
$(function () {
    $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
        endDate : new Date(),
        todayHighlight : true
    });
});
```

For more details check this out https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html?highlight=startdate#quick-reference

Answer (score 3):

Disable all past date

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            /*--FOR DATE----*/
            var date = new Date();
            var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());

            //Date1
            $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTranDate').datepicker({
              format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
              todayHighlight:'TRUE',
              startDate: today,
              endDate:0,
              autoclose: true
            });

        });
</script>
```

Disable all future date

```
 var date = new Date();
 var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());

   //Date1
   $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTranDate').datepicker({
       format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
       todayHighlight:'TRUE',
       minDate: today,
       autoclose: true
   });
```

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ritwika/gsvh83ry/

```
**With three fields having date greater than the **
<input type="text" type="text" class="form-control datepickstart" />
<input type="text" type="text" class="form-control datepickend" />
<input type="text" type="text" class="form-control datepickthird" />

var date = new Date();
 date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);
$('.datepickstart').datepicker({
 autoclose: true,
 todayHighlight: true,
 format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  startDate: date
});
$('.datepickstart').datepicker().on('changeDate', function() {
    var temp = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    var d = new Date(temp);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
  $('.datepickend').datepicker({
 autoclose: true,
 format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
 startDate: d
}).on('changeDate', function() {
    var temp1 = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    var d1 = new Date(temp1);
   d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + 1);
  $('.datepickthird').datepicker({
 autoclose: true,
 format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
 startDate: d1
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply **add data attribute in html input tag**:

In rails html :

```
<%= form.text_field :appointment_date, 'data-provide': 'datepicker', 'data-date-start-date': "+0d" %>
```

HTML :

```
<input data-provide="datepicker" data-date-start-date="+0d" type="text" name="appointment_date" id="appointment_date">
```

Comment: `data-date-start-date="+0d"` did it. Thanks

Comment: I am working on rails and it helped me, upvoted.  Provided `data:{ provide:'datepicker', 'date-start-date': "+1d"}` for getting dates from tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

**In html**

```
<input class="required form-control" id="d_start_date" name="d_start_date" type="text" value="">
```

**In Js side**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var dateToday = new Date();
        dateToday.setDate(dateToday.getDate());

        $('#d_start_date').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: dateToday
        })

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

to disable past date just use :

```
  $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
       format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
       startDate: 'today'
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

```
$('.input-group.date').datepicker({
     format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
     startDate: new Date()
});
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. You should give an answer that fixes the problem, explain _why_ it works, explain _how_ it works, this way other people can learn. How did you come up with this answer? That is something you should include in your answers. Your answer is not helpful to other readers in it's current state.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what format you put on the datepicker
So first we gave it the format.

```
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd;
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm;
    } 
    var today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd; //Here you put the format you want
```

Then Pass the datepicker (depends on the version you using, could be startDate or minDate which is my case )

```
    //Datetimepicker
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            minDate: today, //pass today's date
            daysOfWeekDisabled: [0],
            locale: 'es',
            inline: true,
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm', //format of my datetime (to save on mysqlphpadmin)
            sideBySide: true
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find your solution in this link below: https://codepen.io/ahmetcadirci25/pen/NpMNzJ

Thats work for me.

My code:

```
        var date = new Date();
        date.setDate(date.getDate());

        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            isRTL: false,
            format: 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:ii',
            autoclose: true,
            language: 'tr',
            startDate: date
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to disable the startDate and endDate dynamically based on one on another you can you this.

```
$('#date2').datepicker({
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            clearBtn : true
        }).on('show', function(e){
            var date = $('#date3').datepicker('getDate');
            if(date){
             $('#date2').datepicker('setEndDate', date);
                }
    });

        $('#date3').datepicker({
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            clearBtn : true
        }).on('show', function(e){
            var date = $('#date2').datepicker('getDate');
            if(date){
             $('#date3').datepicker('setStartDate', date);
                }
    });
```

If your requirement is just disabled past dates then you can use below snippet.

```
$('#date2').datepicker({
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            clearBtn : true,
            startDate : new Date()
        })
```

If your requirement is just disabled future dates then you can use below snippet.

```
 $('#date2').datepicker({
                todayHighlight: true,
                autoclose: true,
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                clearBtn : true,
                endDate : new Date()
            })
```

I hope it will help someone.