# Bootstrap datetimepicker startDate does not disable past dates

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, date, datetimepicker

I use bootstrap datetimepicker and I want to disable the past days but `startDate` option did not work:

```
var now = new Date();
var tomorrow = now.getFullYear() + "-" + (now.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + (now.getDate() + 1) + " " + now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds();
$('#end_at').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss',
    startDate: tomorrow
});
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60396540/7772054) answer will help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to use the [`minDate`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#mindate) option of the date***time***picker:

```
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
$("#end_at").datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    minDate: tomorrow
});
```

Comment: dblclick day then close datetimepicker,How is this possible in Bootstrap Datetimepicker?

Comment: This is working fine.but if I'm coming in this page in edit mode the value I set is not displaying,Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time. The option `minDate` is deprecated. the new one is `startDate`

So you can use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
        format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii",
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: true,
        startDate: "2013-02-14 10:00",
        minuteStep: 10
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[startDate](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate) api will helps to disable past date

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
        $(".dates").datepicker({
        format:'dd-mm-yyyy',
        startDate:new Date(),
        autoclose:true
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#DateFrom').datepicker('setStartDate', moment(new Date(2022,08,01)).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
```