# bootstrap datepicker not disabled previous dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i am using [bootstrap datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) and i want to disabled previous dates but nothing will work.

this is what i tried so far

```
<input type="text" name="a" class="datepicker form-control"/>

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
    minDate: new Date(),
    maxDate: '+1y'
});

////////

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
    startDate: '05-18-2016'
});
```

but nothing will work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap datepicker disabling past dates without current date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123056/bootstrap-datepicker-disabling-past-dates-without-current-date)

Comment: startDate: new Date()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  onRender: function(date) {
    return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
  }
});
```