# How to hide the previous dates in bootstrap date picker?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I am using boot strap date picker control for displaying date. I want to hide the previous dates in date picker. How to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123056/bootstrap-datepicker-disabling-past-dates-without-current-date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restrict the selectable date ranges in Bootstrap Datepicker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933173/how-to-restrict-the-selectable-date-ranges-in-bootstrap-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);

$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: date
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcqM7/513/)