# bootstrap date picker start and end date for 3 fields

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have used the following date picker function for start date.

```
var date = new Date();
     date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);
    $('.datepickstart').datepicker({
     autoclose: true,
     todayHighlight: true,
     format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
      startDate: date
    })
```

Pls give me a solution for an end date to be greater than that of selected start date for the above used code. And also the third date field to be greater than of second field. Pls provide me a solution. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. But the start date  to be  greater than current date

Comment: You should try `minDate` and/or `startDate` options, it will help you in solving your problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16123142/1817690

Comment: If its for 2 fields this works fine. I have to compare 3 date fields each to be greater than before.

Comment: pls any one of u provide me solution for comparision of 3 date fields each to be greater than previous.