# How to show past dates for selection in bootstrap date picker?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, datepicker, selection

I am currently able to select the dates from the present date and so on.

Comment: may be some configuration problem.

Comment: look, somewhere used, `minDate: 'todays date'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap datepicker disabling past dates without current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123056/bootstrap-datepicker-disabling-past-dates-without-current-date)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div class="container">
    <input id="datepicker" width="270" />
</div>
```